# Drupal composer install: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: drupal-8

I am using `drupal 8` and I am trying to install the Search API Solr module each time I run the command.

`composer require drupal/search_api_solr`

I am getting this error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.

Here is the screenshot of the error I am getting. Could anyone please help me

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Which Drupal Core version do you use ?
It could be related to the symfony/event-dispatcher library.

Can you try `composer require symfony/event-dispatcher:"4.3.4 as 3.4.99" drupal/search_api_solr` ?

More infos here : https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2876675#comment-13272878

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the module you are trying to install needs some additional package.

Comment: yes I am trying to update the solarium library using "composer require solarium/solarium:^5.1"